# problem sizing android view to standard pdf size

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, pdf

I'm trying to generate a pdf document from a dynamically built android view. No matter what I do the android view is not re-sizing to be properly drawn on the pdf. Also pdf's are I guess are sized in points, while the view is currently setup in pixels.

```
    private var heightInPixels = 1100
    private var widthInPixels = 850
    private val heightLetterPaperInPoints = 792
    private val widthLetterPaperInPoints  = 612

    private fun createPdf() {
        try {
            val data = viewModel.getData(info, requireContext())
            val view2: View =
                LayoutInflater.from(requireContext()).inflate(R.layout.pdf_layout, null)
            val titleTextView = view2.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.title)
            val selectionsContainer = view2.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.selections_container)
            for (item in data) {
                val selectionViewBinding = ItemPdfSelectionBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
                selectionViewBinding.itemTitle.text = item.title
                selectionViewBinding.selectionName.text = item.selectionName
                selectionsContainer.addView(selectionViewBinding.root)
            }
            val pageInfo =
                PageInfo.Builder(widthLetterPaperInPoints, heightLetterPaperInPoints, 1).create()
            val page = pdfDocument.startPage(pageInfo)
            view2.measure(
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                    (widthInPixels).toInt(),
                    View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED
                ),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                    (heightInPixels).toInt(),
                    View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED
                )
            )
            view2.layout(0, 0, widthInPixels, heightInPixels)
            view2.draw(page.canvas)
            pdfDocument.finishPage(page)
        } catch (t: Throwable) {

        }
    }
```

I also tried:

view2.scaleX = .72
view2.scaleY = .72

before measuring the view and that also did nothing.

Comment: Why are you even trying to do that? You're not going to like the result if you do-  a pixel isn't a constant size.  So if you make a view 1100 pixels high, on some device that will be 7 inches.  On others it will be less than 3.  You should pretty much never hardcode anyting to a pixel size on Android.  Generally what you want to do is to specify the view size either to fill an available space or to a size in DP, and scale the pdf to the view size.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have used `View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED` to measure the view.

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec) this means

> The parent has not imposed any constraint on the child. It can be whatever size it wants.

This means you have put no restrictions on the view size so it draws it as big as it wants and thus the width and height in pixels you have given it are ignored.

You should use `View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST` to tell the view it cannot be more than the width of the PDF page (as measured at 72 postscript points (pixels) per inch). Then it will use the pixel size you provide as a maximum

You can also `View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY` but things like centring a view will behave differently.